# Change Jquery está sendo acionado sem ter mudança

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Tenho um código JS que da o valor para um slider de preço, e nesse JS tem um change que está sendo acionado e dentro do change tem um trigger que aciona outra parte do JS que faz o post e redireciona a página mas o change está sendo acionado sem ter mudança nenhuma e a pagina fica recarregando toda hra, código:

```
/*slider jQuery UI*/
(function () {   
    var pdtPrice = $('form[name="workcontrol_filter"]').find('input[name="pdt_price"]');
    var pdtMinPrice = parseInt(pdtPrice.attr('data-min'));
    var pdtMaxPrice = parseInt(pdtPrice.attr('data-max'));

    var pdtStepPrice = parseInt(pdtPrice.attr('data-step'));
    var pdtRangePrice = parseInt(pdtPrice.attr('data-range'));

    $("#slider_price").slider({
        range: true,
        min: pdtMinPrice,
        max: pdtMaxPrice,
        values: [pdtStepPrice, pdtRangePrice],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("R$ " + ui.values[0] + " - R$ " + ui.values[1]);
        },
        // Esse change está sendo acionado sem ter alteração nenhuma no slider_price
        change: function (event, ui) {
            pdtPrice.val(ui.values[0] + ',' + ui.values[1]);
            //alert('FOI ACIONADO');
            $('form[name="workcontrol_filter"]').trigger('change');
        }
    });

    if (pdtMinPrice === pdtMaxPrice) {
        $("#slider_price").slider("option", "disabled", true);
    }

    $("#amount").val("R$ " + $("#slider_price").slider("values", 0) + " - R$ " + $("#slider_price").slider("values", 1));
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider_price"></div>
```

Código que o trigger aciona:

```
/*change form*/
$('html').on('change', 'form[name="workcontrol_filter"]', function () {
    $.post(action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200, function () {
            window.location.href = BASE + '/' + data.redirect;
        });
    }, 'json');
});
```

Então alguem sabe porque isso acontece?
E não sei se isso tem importancia, mas uso twig para o html.

Comment: Olá Wiliam, podes criar um exemplo que corra, no jsFiddle ou na ferramenta aqui do site?

Comment: Não sou especialista em jquery mas, seu `onchange` está dentro de um `document.ready` ?? Penso que seja uma boa tentativa, caso não esteja assim, usar, pois garante que só será disparado o evento, após carregar toda a página, sempre.